# Set custom ssh key in sourcetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree, ssh-keys

I'm using `SourceTree` for `macos`, when I add account, choose ssh key option is missing. It allows me to use only `id_rsa`, but I have to use separate key `~/.ssh/custom_github`.

Any idea how can I proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on mac. There was no option within SourceTree to change keys.

However, I did use [the information here](https://www.vvse.com/blog/blog/2021/11/02/how-to-use-an-alternative-ssh-key-with-bitbucket-in-sourcetree-for-macos/) to get around it.

This will generate a new key from within SourceTree for a particular account.

Not the exact fix you wanted but got me over the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A dirty workaround:

1. Generate new RSA keys through sourcetree interface
2. Using Terminal or iTerm2: go to .ssh folder in your user profile
3. Delete generated keys, they are likely to follow sourcetree naming convention: username-Bitbucket.pub
4. Create a link to your own keys with ln -s